# R.utils::withTimeout waits forever

Tags: r

```
t <- R.utils::withTimeout(readline(), timeout=1, onTimeout = 'error')
```

The above line is supposed to wait 1 second for a input. But in fact it just sits there and wait for forever.

What is wrong?

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 19.10

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.8.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.8.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.1    magrittr_1.5      beepr_1.3         tools_3.6.1       audio_0.1-6       stringi_1.4.3    
 [7] R.methodsS3_1.8.0 stringr_1.4.0     R.utils_2.9.2     R.oo_1.23.0
```

Comment: Strange, it times out for me. I do have to press Enter though. `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @IanCampbell edited